# What is the explicit formula for the staircase function $S(x)$ defined in terms of the zeta zeros?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Riemann and von Mangoldt derived explicit formulas for the Riemann prime power counting function $J(x)$ and the second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)$ respectively via the following relationships.

**(1)** $\quad J(x)=\frac{1}{2\ \pi\ i}\int_{a-\infty\ i}^{a+\infty\ i}\log\zeta(s)\,\frac{x^s}{s}\ ds=li(x)-\sum _\rho Ei\left(\log(x)\ \rho\right)-\log (2)+\int_x^{\infty } \frac{1}{t \left(t^2-1\right) \log (t)} \, dt$

**(2)** $\quad\psi(x)=\frac{1}{2\ \pi\ i}\int_{a-\infty\ i}^{a+\infty\ i}\left(−\frac{\zeta′(s)}{\zeta(s)}\right)\frac{x^s}{s}\ ds=x-\sum_\rho\frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\log(2\ \pi)-\frac{1}{2}\log(1-x^{-2})$

Note that the integral in (1) and (2) above also applies to the staircase function $S(x)$ as illustrated in (3) below which seems to imply the possible existence of an explicit formula for the staircase function expressed in terms of the zeta zeros.

**(3)** $\quad S(x)=\frac{1}{2\ \pi\ i}\int_{a-\infty\ i}^{a+\infty\ i}\zeta(s)\,\frac{x^s}{s}\ ds$

**Question 1**: Is it possible to derive an explicit formula for the staircase function $S(x)$ defined in terms of the zeta zeros?

**Question 2**: Assuming the answer to question 1 above is yes, what is the explicit formula for the staircase function $S(x)$ defined in terms of the zeta zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've derived an explicit formula for $S(x)$ from the explicit formula for $Q(x)$ based on the relationship between $S(x)$ and $Q(x)$. The $c(n)$ coefficient referenced in (3) below involves both a Dirichlet convolution and a Dirichlet inverse, but I believe it simplifies such that $c(n)=1$ when $n$ is a square integer ($n\in\{1,4,9,16,...\}$) and $c(n)=0$ when $n$ is not a square integer.

**(1)** $\quad Q(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(n)\,,\quad a(n)=\left|\mu(n)\right|$

**(2)** $\quad Q_o(x)=\frac{6\,x}{\pi^2}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^K\left(\frac{x^{\frac{\rho_k}{2}}\zeta\left(\frac{\rho_k}{2}\right)}{\rho_k \zeta'\left(\rho_k\right)}+\frac{x^{\frac{\rho _{-k}}{2}}\zeta \left(\frac{\rho_{-k}}{2}\right)}{\rho_{-k}\zeta'\left(\rho_{-k}\right)}\right)+1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{x^{-n}\,\zeta(-n)}{(-2\,n)\,\zeta'(-2\,n)}\,,\\$ $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad K\to\infty\land N\to\infty$

**(3)** $\quad S_o(x)=\sum_\limits{n=1}^x c(n)\,Q_o\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$

The following plot illustrates $S_o(x)$ (orange) evaluated at $K=N=200$. $S(x)$ is illustrated in blue as a reference but is mostly hidden under the evaluation of $S_o(x)$. The red discrete portion of the plot illustrates the evaluation of $S_o(x)$ at integer values of $x$.

[image: Illustration of $S_o(x)$]

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. The reason that the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ show up in the first two formulas is because those zeros are actually *poles* of the integrands. Moving the contour of integration results in contribution from the poles of the integrand, not its zeros. But $\zeta(s) \frac{x^s}s$ doesn't have poles at the zeros of $\zeta(s)$; indeed, its only poles are at $x=1$ and $x=0$, and so the formula for $S(x)$ will be the sum of those two residues, which is $x-\frac12$, plus the contribution from the shifted contours (which will not tend to $0$ in this case).

Comment: Great, if you prove me wrong then I will have learned something!

Comment: Greg Martin: I don't believe your answer above is entirely correct. For example, $\zeta'(s)=-s\int_0^\infty T(x)\,dx$ for $\Re(s)>1$ where $T(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\log(n)$ has no poles at the zeta zeros. But note that $\psi(x)$ can be written as a function of $T(x)$ and vice versa. Since $T(x)$ can be written as a function of $\psi(x)$, and $\psi(x)$ can be written as a function of the zeta zeros, it follows that $T(x)$ can be written as a function of the zeta zeros.

Comment: I suspect it might be the same for $S(x)$ as $\vartheta(x)$, $\psi(x)$, $\pi(x)$ and $J(x)$ can all be written as functions of $S(x)$, but I haven't yet derived an inversion formula for $S(x)$ as a function of $\psi(x)$ or $J(x)$.

Comment: @Steven Clark Can you show us how you write $T(x)$ as a function of $\psi(x)$?

Comment: @azerbajdzan Sorry it took so long to respond but I just noticed your request. The relationships are as follows: $T(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{x-1}\psi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ and $\psi(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{x-1}\mu(n)\,T\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$. The function $T(x)=\sum_{n=1}^x \log(n)$ has a very precise asymptotic $T(x)\approx T_{a}(x)=x\,(\log(x)-1)+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)$ with an error bound very close to $\pm\frac{1}{2}\log(x)=\log(\sqrt x)$. I've wondered for quite some time if the relationship between $\psi(x)$ and $T(x)$ and the precision of $T_a(x)$ can somehow be used to prove the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Also, note that $\zeta'(s)=-s\int_0^\infty T(x)\,x^{-s-1}\,dx$ for $\Re(s)>1$, and $T_a(\frac{x}{2\pi})$ provides a pretty good estimate of the number of non-trivial zeta zeros with positive imaginary part less than x.

Comment: With respect to my original question above, note that $S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^x 1=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $T(x)$ are related via their first-order derivatives: $T'(x)=\log(x)\,S'(x)$. This suggests the possible derivation $S(y)=\sum_{n=1}^{y-1}\int_{y_0}^y\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{\log(x)}\,dx$, but one problem I had with this derivation is I can't seem to evaluate the integral $\int_{y_0}^y\frac{\frac{n^2}{n^2 x-x^3}}{\log(x)}\,dx$ where $\frac{n^2}{n^2 x-x^3}=\frac{\partial\left(-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1-\frac{n^2}{x^2}\right)\right)}{\partial x}$.

Comment: @Steven Clark It does not look for a nice formula for $T(x)$ in terms of non-trivial zeros. For $S(x)$ it would be even more cumbersome. I do not think it will lead to a proof of RH.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I agree the explicit formula for $T(x)$ is less elegant than the explicit formula for $\psi(x)$, and I'm not even sure its possible to derive one for $S(x)$, but the explicit formula for $T(x)$ derived from the explicit formula for $\psi(x)$ is analogous to the explicit formula for the fundamental prime counting function $\pi(x)$ derived from the explicit formula for Riemann's prime-power counting function $\Pi(x)$. The explicit formula for $T(x)$ also illustrates explicit formulas can be derived for some functions even though their transforms don't have poles at the zeta zeros.

Comment: With respect to a proof of the Riemann hypothesis, I wasn't suggesting use of an explicit formula for $T(x)$ or $\psi(x)$ for that matter. I was only pointing out that $T(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ are intimately related and $T(x)$ has a very precise error bound, and wondering if these two observations could somehow be leveraged for a proof of the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: The relationship between $T(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ was noticed at least as far back as the 1870s; indeed, that relationship was used by Mertens to prove asymptotic formulas for sums like $\sum_{n\le x} \Lambda(n)/n$–results that are known to be weaker than the prime number theorem itself, much less the sharp version of PNT that the Riemann hypothesis would give. That's not a proof that such leveraging is impossible, but a lot of smart people have looked at these functions over the last century and a half....

Comment: @GregMartin You're more than likely right that if such a leveraging was possible, someone much smarter than myself would have taken advantage of it by now. I still get confused every time I re-investigate the relationship between $T(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ and try to establish an error bound on $\psi(x)$ based on the narrow error bound on $T(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The whole number staircase function (sometimes called the integer floor function, or natural number counting function) may be expressed as,
$$
S(w) = \int_{r=1^-}^{w} \exp^*(dJ(e^v))[\ln r] dr,
$$
where $\ln r$ is the independent variable of the convolution exponential, and the argument of the c.e. is the usual prime-power staircase function (steps of $1/k$ at each $p^k$, $p$ prime; see eg "Riemann's Zeta Function," H.M. Edwards),
$$
dJ(e^u) = \left( \frac{1}{u} - \sum_{\rho} \frac{e^{(\rho-1)u}}{u} - \frac{1}{e^{u}(e^{2u}-1)u} \right),
$$
where the $\rho$ are the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

(Note, for those unfamiliar the convolution exponential (when it converges) is defined as
$$
\exp^*(f) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{*k}}{k!} = \delta_0 + f + f*f/2! + f*f*f/3!+...,
$$
where $\delta_0$ is the Dirac delta function. It has some of the expected properties, like for functions $f$ and $g$ under convergence conditions, $\exp^*(f+g) = \exp^*(f)*\exp^*(g)$, and if $0<f<g$, then $\exp^*(f)<\exp^*(g)$.)

For proof see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218288/how-to-get-the-floor-function-as-a-mellin-inverse-of-the-hadamard-product-of-the).